# Android AsyncTask block the UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

on the onCreate() I'm starting two AsyncTask on paralle, but for some reason the progressbar of the first one is stuck!

```
    @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          new LoadFotos(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
          new BuildTempTable().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
     private class LoadFotos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            Activity activity;
            List<Dokumentation> dokumentationList;
            private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public LoadFotos(Activity activity) {
                this.activity = activity;
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                        this.progressDialog.setTitle(activity.getString("download"));
                this.progressDialog.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.please_wait));
                this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                this.progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
               // background process
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                if(this.progressDialog != null && this.progressDialog.isShowing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
                    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        }

private class BuildTempTable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           // heavy background process
            return null;
        }
}
```

and if I start the BuildTemptable() in the onPostExecute of the LoadFotos, then I'm not able to start new activity.
I thought what ever in the AsyncTask must be independents from the UI.
What the bug here?

Comment: `I thought what ever in the AsyncTask must be independents from the UI.` A progress dialog? And what do you mean with 'stuck'?

Comment: `then I'm not able to start new activity.` There is no code where you try to do that.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. When the activity start a progress dialog appears but it stuck(the progress animation is stuck) until the second asyncTask finish and it continue.

Comment: In the activity there is a button start new activity using intent.

Answer (score 0):

the logic you are using is not the best but it works like is expected. What it can be happening is in your doingBackground is not getting to return null, with that in mind, the post execute method is never archieve. Look for that, i post a code than i try with a similar logic and it works. You can test it yourself.

```
    public class AsyncAtivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_ativity);
            new Count10seconds(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }

        private class Count10seconds extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
            Activity activity;
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            public Count10seconds(Activity activity){
                this.activity = activity;
                this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                this.progressDialog.setTitle("download");
                this.progressDialog.setMessage("plz wait");
                this.progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                this.progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    return null;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                if(this.progressDialog != null && this.progressDialog.isShowing() && !activity.isDestroyed()) {
                    this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i post a code than i try with a similar logic ` ???? I see only one async task suddenly.

Comment: The question is about how to show a progressDialogs in pre execute and why it is not geting dismiss en onPostExecute. I'm showing the problem is not related to the way he show and hide the progress but maybe is in his doInBackground.

Comment: when the two Async. tasks are run, LoadFotos shows a progress dialog, but the progress dialog is stuck for like 2min. maybe because BuildTempTable is very heavy operation ?